# How To Get Values From Parent Table Which Is based On Child Table Spring Boot Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two tables one is User and another is Assign .

User -

```
UserId(Primary Key)  UserName Pwd
1        abc      123
2        xyz      123
```

Assign  -

```
AssignId   WOrk     UserName (Foreign key)
1          Design    1
2          Process   2
```

In user table Userid is the primary key and in assignid table username col is the foreign key which is refering to UserId col in user table.

Now i am using spring and hibernate and from the user i am passing int number in Username column in Assignto table. From that int number as userid want to show the username in jsp page ?

I am new t hibernate and How i can do that ?

Comment: Please have a look at this link on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok sir, i will take care of that. Plz give me solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about hibernate mapping and relations like oneToMany ,manyToOne..
[this tutorial will be helpful for you](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/)